# Fitting three equally sized pdf charts onto one A4 page

Tags: graphics

I have three equally sized pdf charts and I want to fit them side by side, in columns on one A4 page. I tried the code below, but the charts were not side by side but under each other.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{extarticle}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,scale=0.8,center]{a.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,scale=0.8,left]{a.pdf}
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth,scale=0.8,right]{a.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: You cannot set up both `width` and `scale`, the contradict each other. If you remove the `scale`s, you  will get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys `width` and `scale` are contradictory, and the latter is chosen. Specifying `width` only, it behaves as desired. Note the added `%` to get rid of the interword space between the graphics. Also note that specifying the engine to `graphicx` is not necessary.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{extarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{a.pdf}%
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{a.pdf}%
  \includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{a.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\resizebox{width}{height}{object}` as it follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{extarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
 \includegraphics{a.pdf}%
 \includegraphics{a.pdf}%
 \includegraphics{a.pdf}}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The `!` is used to keep the aspect ratio.

Put `\quad` or `\qquad` or `\hspace{}` at the end of the first and the second `\includegraphics` if you need more space between your charts.

If you want that your `figure` fills the line, but dimensions of pictures are too large, add `scale` or `width` as option in `\includegraphics`.